# Is it a good decision to include failed/unsatisfactory result in bachelor's thesis?

Tags: thesis, research-undergraduate

I am conducting a research project under supervision of a professor for the bachelor's thesis.

Among all the tasks agreed between the professor and I, there is one task which was suggested by me. It is an attempt to solve the problem by using a completely different approach from the other one suggested by the professor (which works great). Both of them are part of the project.

It turned out that my idea did not work that marvelous. Although it somehow solved the problem with a better result, the cost (time complexity) is much higher. It is not worth the "extra effort". However, I do not want to consider any technical detail here, and for this question, the problem should be considered as (very) "unsatisfactory" result compared to current State-of-the-Art of the field.

There are theoretical frameworks that support the approach. It is just unfortunate that it does not work that well. I still think it deserves a chapter in the thesis.

It it a bad idea to still include "failed"/unsatisfactory results in the thesis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, you should include that.**

In your particular case, it seems you have actually found something out, namely that the time complexity of the alternate approach is much higher. This may not be immediately useful knowledge, but it is new knowledge nonetheless. (And it could actually be useful to someone else also considering your alternative approach!)

Even if you hadn't found out anything - say you just failed to make it work in a way that doesn't mean anything to anyone else - including your attempt **may** make a lot of sense. As long as you have done enough to have something to write about, you should get credit for it as part of your BSc thesis grade.